# Can't upload file to php server

Tags: android, http-post, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload files from Android mobile phone to server Which based on the following sample code

```
http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106
```

Worked on wifi, but fails on 3G network.

Can anyone help me to solve this kind of issue?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your phone WI-FI is over the server ip where your php code is deployed? There may be internet speed issue while file uploading.

Comment: Post your error log data.

Comment: are u use localhost???

Comment: AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post("http://192.168.xx.xx/aaa.php",params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()

Comment: while using 3G network, the error messages are HTTP Status code 0, connection timeout...etc